# Nested react navigation config could not find redux store in app context

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a react-native app, with redux and react-navigation. I'm trying to create 2 navigators. First one is `stackNavigator`, which includes 4 screens, second one is a `bottomTabBarNavigator`, which includes 2 screens. Both are merged into one with 
`createAppContainer(createStackNavigator(navigator1, navigator2))`
I have also redux.

Everything is working fine except one screen from second navigator. (it has 2 screens, first is working fine, second one is throwing error.

I've changed already AppNavigator connection, from simple

```
export default AppNavigator
```

to

```
export default connect()(AppNavigator)
```

```
App.js - main container
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                        <AppNavigator/>
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}


AppNavigator.js 

const navigator = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {screen: LoginView, navigationOptions: {header: null}},
    Menu: {screen: MenuView},
    Competition: {screen: CompetitionView},
    Map: {screen: CompetitionMapView},
});

const singleNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    CompetitionDetails: {screen: CompetitionDetailsView},
    RouteView: {screen: RouteView}
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
    Main: navigator,
    Competition: singleNavigator
}));

singleNavigator.navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
        header: null,
    };
};

navigator.navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
        header: null,
    };
};

export default connect(undefined,undefined)(AppNavigator);


RouteView.js - component causing error, 

// normal react component with only render and mapStateToProps / mapDispatchToProps funcs

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(RouteView);
```

Everything is working fine, until the RouteView from "singleNavigator". When I pass to this screen, the ressult is below error:

Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(RouteView)". Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or pass a custom React context provider to `<Provider>` and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(RouteView) in connect options.